# RowUpdating event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view and i need to update it with RowUpdating event, but after updating the new values did not appear, database update with the old values.
here is my code

```
 protected void gvContactInfo_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvContactInfo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindingGVContacts(int.Parse(ddlfilterforContact.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
    protected void gvContactInfo_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = ((Label)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblContactidno"));
        DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlInfoType"));
        TextBox txtinfo = ((TextBox)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtValueE"));
        TextBox txtext = ((TextBox)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtExt"));

        string queryContactInfo = "update tblContactInfo set ContactInfoType='"+ddl.SelectedItem.Text+"',ContactInfo='"+txtinfo.Text+"',Ext='"+txtext.Text+"' where ContactID=" + int.Parse(lbl.Text.Trim()) + "";
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryContactInfo, Connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();
        gvContactInfo.EditIndex = -1;
        bindingGVContacts(int.Parse(ddlfilterforContact.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
    protected void gvContactInfo_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvContactInfo.EditIndex = -1;
        bindingGVContacts(int.Parse(ddlfilterforContact.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
```

my databinding code is as follows:

```
public void bindingGVContacts(int contactID)
    {
        int contactID1 = contactID;
        string queryContactInfo = "SELECT * FROM tblContactInfo where ContactID=" +  contactID1 + "";
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        Connection.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter(queryContactInfo, ConnString);
        ad.Fill(ds, "queryContactInfo");
        ad.Fill(dt);
        Connection.Close();
        if (ds.Tables["queryContactInfo"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvContactInfo.Columns[0].Visible = true;
            gvContactInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables["queryContactInfo"];
            gvContactInfo.DataBind();
            gvContactInfo.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            foreach (GridViewRow grow in gvContactInfo.Rows)
            {
                Label lbl = ((Label)grow.FindControl("lblContactidno"));
                DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)grow.FindControl("ddlInfoType"));
                DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ContactNoID=" + lbl.Text.Trim() + "");
                if (dr.Length != 0)
                {
                    ddl.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
                    if (ddl.Items.FindByText(dr[0]["ContactInfoType"].ToString()) != null)
                        ddl.Items.FindByText(dr[0]["ContactInfoType"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            gvContactInfo.DataSource = dt;
            gvContactInfo.DataBind();
            gvContactInfo.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

here is my aspx code of gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvContactInfo" ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Enableviewstate="true"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="gvContactInfo_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvContactInfo_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvContactInfo_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="gvContactInfo_RowCommand"
                    CssClass=" CategoriesTable table table-striped table-bordered CategoriesTable1" 
                    onrowdatabound="gvContactInfo_RowDataBound">
                         <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblContactidno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ContactNoID")%>' Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="INFO Type" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInfoType" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Address" Text="Address"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Email-Personal" Text="Email-Personal"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Email-Work" Text="Email-Work"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Home" Text="Phone-Home"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Work" Text="Phone-Work"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Mobile" Text="Phone-Mobile"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInfoType" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Address" Text="Address"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Email-Personal" Text="Email-Personal"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Email-Work" Text="Email-Work"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Home" Text="Phone-Home"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Work" Text="Phone-Work"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Phone-Mobile" Text="Phone-Mobile"></asp:ListItem>
                                     </asp:DropDownList>
                                 </FooterTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ContactInfo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                                 </FooterTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValueE" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ContactInfo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Extension" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExtension" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ext")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtExtension1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                                 </FooterTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtExt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ext")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="false">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                                     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:Button runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="Insert"></asp:Button>
                                 </FooterTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got another way to update i.e with the help of RowCommand method

```
 protected void gvContactInfo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Update"))
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            Label lbl = ((Label)gvContactInfo.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("lblContactidno"));
            DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)gvContactInfo.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("ddlInfoType"));
            TextBox txtinfo = ((TextBox)gvContactInfo.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("txtValueE"));
            TextBox txtext = ((TextBox)gvContactInfo.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("txtExt"));

            string queryContactInfo = "update tblContactInfo set ContactInfoType='" + ddl.SelectedItem.Text + "',ContactInfo='" + txtinfo.Text + "',Ext='" + txtext.Text + "' where ContactNoID=" + int.Parse(lbl.Text.Trim()) + "";
            Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryContactInfo, Connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
            gvContactInfo.EditIndex = -1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a debugger and check if you are passing the correct (new) value to your sql query string, and use try-catch block to catch any exception when updating.

Also, it is not a good idea to build sql query using string. You should use `Parameter` to prevent SQL-Injection.

This [example](http://xkcd.com/327/) shows what could happen with SQL injection.

And this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) shows how you can prevent SQL injection in C# using `Parameter`

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion i will keep it mind.
but here i am passing the correct values but not getting the newer values into the event.

Comment: so you are not putting the correct value in your SQL query, correct? your SQL came out to be something like [set ContactInfoType='oldValue']? If so, you should probably check your binding.

Comment: A debugger can not only help you check if you are getting the correct value, it can also allow to walk through the steps. Set a debugger at the beginning of the event fired, walk through it step by step, and see if the value is updating at the spot where you're expecting.

Comment: I have checked it but did not get the newer value from the beginning to the end of the event.
I am not able to find the mistake what i have did. Please let me know if there is any mistake in code.

Comment: which line of code are you expecting to get the new value? why didn't you get it? can you you figure out/understand why by looking at that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you are getting the new values in gvContactInfo_RowUpdating change event using break points

Comment: i have checked with the breakpoints and i did not get new values there.

Comment: Just Check whether you are binding in is not postback in page load `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindGVContacts();
    }
}`

Comment: `Label lbl = ((Label)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblContactidno")); String ContactID=lbl.Text; DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlInfoType")); String Type=ddl.Text; `Now just check what you are getting in ContactID and Type .Check whether it is new or old value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the old values directly using the FindControl option like,

```
Label lbl = ((Label)gvContactInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblContactidno"));
```

you should be using the [GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get all the new values as key/value pair.

```
string lblStr = e.NewValues[0].ToString(); //lblContactidno
```

EDIT

You are reading the existing values of your control using the FindControl method in the Row_Updating event. The problem is that your new values hasn't been updated yet and it's in the process to do so. Hence, it's pulling out the old values. Both old & New values are stored in the event **GridViewUpdateEventArgs** as key/value pair. So you have to get the new values from there [*NewValues property*]. The code I have suggested here is to read the value for your label only. check if you're getting the new value for it or not as it's based on the assumption that the label is the first control in the grid.

Comment: when i am using 
string lblStr = e.NewValues[0].ToString(); it gives the new value but when
string lblStr = e.NewValues[1].ToString(); it throws an exception

Comment: Yes i have lable as 1st control and in 2nd dropdown and at 3rd and 4th positions i have textboxes but 
string lblStr = e.NewValues[0].ToString(); gives me the value of 3rd position textbox..

Comment: In your code Out of the four controls, **lbl**, **ddl**, **txtinfo**, & **txtText** were you getting old values for all your controls or just the DropDownList, **ddl**?

Comment: no for all the controls i am getting the old values.